# How do I get this HTML element centered?

Tags: html, css, containers, center

How I want it to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgfnJ.png

**Please note**: Setting a fixed width is not useful here, because that would prevent the boxes from using all available screen space. I need the boxes to stay responsive, but want them to appear centered.

The problem is not so much the centering of the element, but the fact that the element takes up 100% width when it doesn't need to.

---

I have a container with several boxes, which are set to float.

```
<div id="contentBox">
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56BJP/

The container div takes up 100% width, even if it doesn't require it all, so I can't get it centered with margin: 0 auto.

How do I get the container to not needlessly take up 100% width?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

Comment: Note you must clear after floating elements. And in this case it seems you don't need floating nor positioned elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set a width for that element to shrink to fit it's content. You can simply add the CSS `display: inline-block;` and it will shrink to the right size. Additionally, you can do the same with the child blocks, removing the need to float the elements in the first place.

Comment: The container also needs "text-align:center", then it works! Thank you. It does add spaces at newlines though, but for now it's the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `width` to your `div` and center :

```
<div id="contentBox" style="width:500px;margin:0 auto">
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
</div>
```

In your fiddle , you should add  `width` to your class :

```
#contentBox
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50%;//fixe a width
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/56BJP/3/)

Comment: If you look at the layout, it's implied that the boxes are supposed to be responsive, so setting a fixed width for the container is no solution here. I clarified that in the question.

Comment: You can fixe a width using% instead of pixels , this way width will depend on the width of your screen

Comment: There's still empty horizontal space in the container, depending on the screen size, so the boxes don't appear centered.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you do not want to set the width of the container div explicitly,
you can remove `float: left;` from `a` and set the container's `display` to `table`.

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/56BJP/2/

```
#contentBox
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}

a.content
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 310px;
    height: 174px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #000 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, like the other answers, that doesn't allow the boxes to adapt to different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You need fix width for `margin` to get worked. More importantly you always need  to clear floated elements with clearfix:

```
<div id="contentBox">
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <a class="content"></a>
    <div class="clear"></div> <!-- clear float elements -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contentBox {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/56BJP/6/)

Comment: Don't want a fixed width, as that beats the whole purpose of the flexible box layout.

Comment: @user3653087 You can use `margin-left` with the percentage width. in that case you can write `#contentBox {  width: 80%; margin: 0 10%;}`

Comment: There's still empty horizontal space in the container, depending on the screen size, so that is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#contentBox {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56BJP/4/

Comment: The layout is supposed to be responsive, so setting a fixed width is not a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If `#contentBox` doesn't have a fixed width, you can add `margin: 0 auto` to `a.content`, which do have it. Then, just use

```
a.content {
    display: block;
    width: 310px;
    height: 174px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/56BJP/5/)

Comment: I want the boxes to adapt to the screen size, but that would always display only one box per line.

Answer (score 0):

try using the css

```
#contentBox {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;  }
```

only because inline styling's have been deprecated in modern browers

Comment: or will be deprecated soon

Comment: The layout is supposed to be responsive, so setting a fixed width is not a solution here.